# How to align text next to bullseye

Tags: html, css, styles, alignment

I have created a bullseye logo using CSS and want to put a text aligned next to the logo.

```css
#logo{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    background-clip:content-box;
    padding:5px;
    border:5px solid red;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo" style="float:left;"><b ><span style="margin-left: 20px;p-bottom: -50px;"> text123</span></b></div>
```

Comment: Dont use float on the logo. Second, if this text  should be positioned with the logo you could make the #logo div position:relative, and the text position:absolute, so if the logo moves so does the text

Comment: or you can extend margin-left of span simply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox`:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}

#logo{
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:red;
    background-clip:content-box;
    padding:5px;
    border:5px solid red;
    color:red;
}

#text {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 12px
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo"></div>
  <div id="text">text123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want text to appear next to the logo.